# How to use @NotNull with spring boot?

Tags: validation, spring-boot, bean-validation

I have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which have it's version managed by

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

And I have this piece:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
//other imports ommited

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "collector")
public class CollectorProperties {

    @NotNull
    private String urlCDI;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And my `SpringApplication.run` class has this pice:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ComponentScan({ "otherPackages", "packageWhereCollectorPropertiesIs" })
```

When I have my `application.properties` with this line

```
collector.urlCDI=https://www.cetip.com.br/Home
```

It works as it was supposed inside other spring beans:

```
//@Component class variables:
@Autowired
private CollectorProperties props;

   //inside some method
    URL url = new URL(props.getUrlCDI());
```

But when I remove it or alter property key I get lots of NPE instead of validations errors. What I'm doing wrong? Doesn't `hibernate-validator` contains an implementation of `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add ´@Validated' annotation to your properties class

Comment: Indeed, if I looked more carefully [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation) I would've noticed. Thanks, now it works!