# Make a field in Abstract class mandatory while persisting Concrete class object to db

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

```
public abstract class Parent{
  @NotNull
  private String appId;
}

@Documnet
public class child1 extends Parent{
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...more fields
  ...getters setters
}

@Documnet
public class child2 extends Parent{
  @Id
  private String id;
  ...more fields
  ...getters setters
}
```

I want to make sure that each time when I persist Child1 or Child2 in mongodb appId field has a valid value otherwise I want my code to throw some Exception or error.

I do not want to explicitly check each time that appId has a value.It should be a one time thing where you just configure once and it is reflected for every class that extends Parent

I am using spring-boot and mongodb as databse.

```
ependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
  implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.1'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'

  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

  compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-security', version: '2.2.6.RELEASE'
  compile('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.6.RELEASE')
  compile('org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.1')

  compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
  annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Take a look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51832507/3710490)

Comment: tried adding @Validated annotation to Parent Class still no change when I save Child1 or 2 without appId it gets saved to DB without any error

Comment: Try to put it on Child1 and Child2 classes... Maybe, since Parent is abstract class, @Validated ignores...

Answer (score 0):

Heres how I resolved this issue, Not sure if this is a concrete solution

```
public abstract class Parent {
    @NotNull
    private String appId;
}

@Document
public class Child extends Parent{

    @Id
    private String id;

}
```

create beans for **ValidatingMongoEventListener** and **LocalValidatorFactoryBean**

```
@Configuration
public class SomeClass {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener createValidatingMongoEventListenerBean(LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean){
            return  new ValidatingMongoEventListener(localValidatorFactoryBean);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean createLocalValidatorFactoryBean(){
        return  new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

}
```

now if we try to persist **Child** class that extends our **Parent** class without **appId** it will throw **ConstraintViolationException**